# How to link a discord channel with python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I am working on making a discord bot for a support server of my friends the one thing i am stuck up on is I want the bot to tell a user to go to a specific channel with the #channel that way they can click on it for convince I have tried some things but I am relatively new to coding any ideas. this is all that i have so far.

```
import discord
import os 
import keep_alive
if message.content.startswith("!help"):
    await message.channel.send("To contact a support person go to")
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you should use a **bot command decorator** rather than looking for the command statement in the messages content.

In this command you should extract the **target channel object** through its **ID**, and mention that channel in your message. In this way users will be able to click on the mention and be redirected to that channel.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild # The guild to which the channel belongs to
    target_channel = guild.get_channel(channel_ID_goes_here)
    await ctx.send(f"To contact a support person go to {target_channel.mention}")
```

Comment: You can also do it with <#CHANNEL_ID>, probably that would be a bit easier